# Unable to load form coming from another template to a existing module

Tags: angularjs

I have implemented a form with a particular controller and then after it is storing in a scope object and then after I assigned that scope object to a service property to share n number of controllers. After assignment the data to service property I am redirecting to another page where a form is their and it have some fields but I am unable to show the form in the web page.

Example: index.html:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl_1"> ... ..... </body>
```

main.js:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.service("myService",function(){
    this.Details = "";
    this.setDetails = function(details){
        this.Details = details;
    };
    this.getDetails = function(){
        return this.Details;
    } });
```

`app.controller("ctrl_1",function($scope,myService){` after passing the data in service I redirect to `index2.html` `window.location("index2.html"); });`

```
app.controller("ctrl_2",function($scope,myService){   });
```

index2.html:

```
<body ng-app="app" controller="ctrl_2"> ..`enter code here` ....enter code here </body>
```

In this way I define, but I am unable to run the `index2.html` page.

Answer (score 0):

You need a routing module such as `ngRoute` or `ui.router`. They will help you with redirection to other pages. Here is a quick demo for your scenario:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "index.html"
    })
    .when("/page2", {
      templateUrl: "index2.html"
    });
});
app.service("myService", function() {
  this.Details = "";
  this.setDetails = function(details) {
    this.Details = details;
  };
  this.getDetails = function() {
    return this.Details;
  }
});

app.controller("ctrl_1", function($scope, myService, $location) {
  $scope.redirect = function(path) {
    $location.url(path);
  }
});

app.controller("ctrl_2", function($scope, myService, $location) {
  $scope.redirect = function(path) {
    $location.url(path);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-view></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="index.html">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl_1">
      Page 1 (index.html)
      <br>
      <button ng-click="redirect('/page2')">Redirect</button>
    </div>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="index2.html">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl_2">
      Page 2 (index2.html)
      <br>
      <button ng-click="redirect('/')">Go back</button>
    </div>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```